# JFXComboBox and Postgresql

Tags: javafx

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente problema. En una base de datos en postgres quiero poner de una tabla los id de algunos usuarios en un JFXComboBox, pero como sabemos estos id son identifacoderos que realmento no dicen mucho a quien pertenecen, entonces quiero de esta misma tabla coger los nombros de los usuarios e introducirlos en el JFXComboBox pero que al seleccionar un nombre me muestre esntonces el id al que pertenece segun esta tabla. No hay problemas en la vinculacion con la BD solo en como hacer esta asociacion.
Gracias

Comment: ¿Y el problema entonces cuál es? Ya lo has dicho, selecciona los nombres y muéstralos. ¿Qué has intentado al respecto, qué error tienes?

Comment: Si, buenas, quiero seleccionar un nombre y mostrar su id en vez del nombre